# How to validate special character from the textbox without using Validate plugin on jquery

Tags: jquery

How to validate special characters in a textbox without using Validate plugin on JQuery

Comment: Your question isn't too clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this javascript

```
function checkSpecialKeys(e) {
            if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 40)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
```

Implement it on the onkeydown or onkeyup attribute of the textbox.

You can add or remove the keys you which to validate by specifying the key code.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete special characters and allow only words, spaces and numbers:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function(){
     var text=$(this).val();
     $(this).val(text.replace(/[^\w\d\s]/,""));
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use regular expression with basic javascript.
I will prefer something like http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/perfect-javascript-form-validation.html